# How to use environtment.ts to index.html for title to be dynamic with environtment

Tags: html, angular

I wanna try to change title index.html with organization in environment, so when you change environment, it will dynamicly change the title. How to change it with angular?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Title` provided from angular: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Title

```js
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';


  constructor(private titleService: Title) { 
    // set the title dynamically
    titleService.setTitle(environment.myTitle);
  }
```